# Is the scope of Flash in JSF the same as session scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsf-2

From the [javadocs of Flash class in JSF](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/context/Flash.html):

> The Flash concept is taken from Ruby on Rails and provides a way to
>   pass temporary objects between the user views generated by the faces
>   lifecycle. As in Rails, anything one places in the flash will be
>   exposed to the next view encountered by the same user session and then
>   cleared out. It is important to note that “next view” may have the
>   same view id as the previous view.

Doesn't the above paragraph equate the `Flash` scope to `session` scope ? If not , then what am I missing ?

P.S: Since the concept has been borrowed from Ruby On Rails so I added that tag here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will be exposed to the next view encountered by the same user session and **then cleared out.**

The emphasized part is the difference: If you put something into the session scope, it will remain there unless you remove it (or the session ends). If you put something into the flash scope, it will be removed automatically once the next view has been rendered (or the session ends).

Comment: can we say that flash scope lies between session and request scope then ?

Comment: Yes. Closer to request than session though. It has effectively a lifetime of 2 HTTP requests. Thus, scopes are arranged as "none" < "request" < "flash" < "view" < "session" < "application".